# footstep planner

Tags: ros, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I use the footstep_planner and I have a question, respectively I am searching for a parameter, which I does not found.

Where can I specify the position of the foots from the robot. (I gave the planner a start position, but from where he get exactly the information about the position of left and right foot from the robot.)

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62138/footstep-planner/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Starting feet can be set in the API with the function "setStart". There is no callback for that exposed, instead the callback uses the starting pose (x,y,theta) to place the feet around it (left and right).

In the footstep_navigation node, the robot's current foot locations from TF are used.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0